# Create Multiple Single Post Pages with different categories showing in slider on each one

Tags: php, wordpress

I have built out the below page in wordpress, single.php, with a custom slider on the top. Currently the slider is showing the posts from all categories with the post body showing the correct content.

What I need is 3 pages, single1.php, single2.php, and single3.php showing only the posts from category 1 on single1.php, category 2 on single2.php, and category 3 on single3.php.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class="cap-cont">
                <div class="cap">CHOOSE A AUTHOR</div>
                <div class="auth-slide">
            <?php

$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'rand' ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $content .= '<div><a href="';
    $content .= get_permalink();
    $content .= '">';
    $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail();
    $content .= '</a></div>';
endwhile;
echo $content;  

            ?>  
        </div>          

        </div>          
        <div class="y-dot">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Orange-Dotted-Line.png">
        </div>
        <div class="info-cont">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="name">
                    <?php the_field('name'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="lname">
                    <?php the_field('lname'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="spec">
                    <?php the_field('spec'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="m-quote">
                    <?php the_field('main_quote'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="gtk">
                    GET TO KNOW YOUR AUTHOR
                </div>
                <div class="quote">
                    <p class="ques">
                        <?php the_field('qus_one'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="answ">
                        <?php the_field('ans_one'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="ques">
                        <?php the_field('qus_two'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="answ">
                        <?php the_field('ans_two'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="ques">
                        <?php the_field('qus_three'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="answ">
                        <?php the_field('ans_three'); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pic-cont">
                <div class="call">
                    <strong>CALL (555) 555-5555</strong>
                </div>


                <div class="pic">
                    <img src="<?php the_field('authimg'); ?>" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="bsbhby">
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Footer_25.png">
            </div>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!--col-md-12 col-xs-12 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating category templates.  For example, if you have a category named "puzzle" then create a new php file in the theme called "**category-puzzle.php**" and only posts within that category will display.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect that fixed my issue, I just need to figure out how to filter the categories in the slider based on what post is selected but I will make a different ticket for that.